# Not able to access the class which is not inside in app_code folder in VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have created a solution in VS 2015 given below. I have added a folder Mapper and inside that a class DefaultMapper.cs. I want to access this class(DefaultMapper.cs) from defalut.cs. I could not able to access it. 
If I put the same class inside App_code folder then I am able to access it.
I am also using public access modifier everywhere.
Can anybody help me on it. Thanks in advance.

"[image]"

Comment: make sure that you are using the correct namespace

Comment: Thanks for reply. This option also I tried before I post this question but this one also not working. And I notice that If there is any compiler error in this class(DefaultMapper.cs) then during build time its not throwing any error. Not sure why VS 2015 is behaving like this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add namespace like this (ShortCut **CTRL + .** (dot) will suggest you to add this while you are trying to create an instance.),

```
using POC.Mapper;
```

then you can create instance,

```
DefaultMapper test = new DefaultMapper();
```

or

```
POC.Mapper.DefaultMapper test = new POC.Mapper.DefaultMapper();
```

You told that you able to call this class if you put it inside app_code. Check namespaces in `Default.cs` class and you will see that `using POC.App_Code` is already there. Thats why you can call from there.

Hope helps,

Comment: Thanks for reply. This option also I tried before I post this question but this one also not working. And I notice that If there is any compiler error in this class(DefaultMapper.cs) then during build time its not throwing any exception. Not sure why VS 2015 is behaving like this.